# C unused pointer parameter

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have found the following function definition in Linux source:

```
static int __ref kernel_init(void *unused)
{
    int ret;

    kernel_init_freeable();
    /* need to finish all async __init code before freeing the memory */
    async_synchronize_full();
    ftrace_free_init_mem();
    free_initmem();
    mark_readonly();

    /*
     * Kernel mappings are now finalized - update the userspace page-table
     * to finalize PTI.
     */
    pti_finalize();

    system_state = SYSTEM_RUNNING;
    numa_default_policy();

    rcu_end_inkernel_boot();

    if (ramdisk_execute_command) {
        ret = run_init_process(ramdisk_execute_command);
        if (!ret)
            return 0;
        pr_err("Failed to execute %s (error %d)\n",
               ramdisk_execute_command, ret);
    }

    /*
     * We try each of these until one succeeds.
     *
     * The Bourne shell can be used instead of init if we are
     * trying to recover a really broken machine.
     */
    if (execute_command) {
        ret = run_init_process(execute_command);
        if (!ret)
            return 0;
        panic("Requested init %s failed (error %d).",
              execute_command, ret);
    }
    if (!try_to_run_init_process("/sbin/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/etc/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/sh"))
        return 0;

    panic("No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. "
          "See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.");
}
```

My question concerns the *unused* argument to the function. I have seen some other questions where one can use the GCC attribute specifier to declare the argument as unused and some other techniques, but this one looks like it would generate some weird compiler warnings since I see no usage of any suppression techniques here. Does anyone know what is the use of this argument here?

Comment: You can also suppress such warnings/errors using the compiler command line. Maybe it's there?

Comment: @kichik If it is I have no idea how I would find it in the Linux repository.

Comment: Hmm, I would have expected a `(void) unused;` in the body.

Comment: The function is defined here if anyone might find some hint to this. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/init/main.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unused parameter is there, because `kernel_init` is run as a `kernel_thread` which expects a pointer to `int(void*)` function as the first argument.

From [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/init/main.c#L632):

> ```
> pid = kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS);
> ```

Comment: This is fine, but it doesn't change the fact that the argument is unused.

Comment: I don't understand. Yes, your statement is true. How is it relevant? The reason for `kenrel_init` having an unused argument is that it is run as a kernel thread that uses `kernel_thread` as the interface and takes `int(void*)` function pointer. The abi consistency, code readability is the reason. Passing another type to `kernel_thread` would be a warning, writing a wrapper/overload around `kenrel_thread` to pass `int(void)` would be a lot of useless code.

Comment: I asked purely because I was wondering if the compiler would complain for such a method.

Comment: Kernel is compiled with gcc. [Gcc has a -Wunused-parameter warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). The warnings used by linux kernel differ from tree to tree and from version to version.